# CSV Import in Gephi

Tags: r, csv, graph, gephi

I've created my network using R from a large dataset. I've used a smaller one to test and wrote my own plotter to show how I'd like it displayed, I just can't seem to get it right....

This Image shows how my network should look. I've tried square matrices of data (36x36) and a 1x36 exported as CSV, neither of which give the result I desire.

[image: Desired Network]

Ignoring the bigger circles, I'd like the network displayed in the image above.

Version 1 - 1x36 - https://www.dropbox.com/s/k4a7tc0kwlfqd0l/ABC.csv

Version 2 - 36x36 - https://www.dropbox.com/s/mmu7spix076bn6e/DEF.csv

The structure is as follows. Row 1 & Column 1 - node names. All numbers decide if an edge exists or not (0 or 1).

When I try to import these files, Gephi interprets them in an unusual way.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Cheers

Comment: what do you mean by "interprets them in an unusual way"?

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you to use **rgexf**. It is available at
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgexf/index.html

I assume that you have a edgelist already. Let me call it x.

```
library(rgexf)
data <- edge.list(x)  # It creates two objects from your edgelist: data$nodes and data$edges 
g <- write.gexf(nodes=data$nodes,edges=data$edges,...) # It creates a graph in gexf format, here you can add nodes' attributes, edges' attributes, etc... 
print(g, file="mygraph.gexf") # It saves the graph
```

For more details. The manual is here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rgexf/rgexf.pdf)

Comment: You should add more detailed information rather then a single line response.

Comment: Ok, it is my first time. Hope it is better now